# Where's the Backbone require.js dependency being resolved in this example?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

In Addy Osmani's ToDo MVC example for require.js + Backbone: https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/main.js, he's using

```
Backbone.history.start() // line #31
```

without actually requiring Backbone. How/why does this work? Is the shim enabling this? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look in the code, [view/app.js](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/views/app.js) is actually requiring Backbone.

And the backbone shim is exporting the **global** Backbone variable.

If no other modules will actually require the shim, it won't be loaded, so it won't be accessible.

You can try to remove the 'views/app' requirements in main.js to see for yourself.

Comment: Hmm...it appears removing views/app doesn't cause a problem, but removing routers/router makes Backbone.history.start() stop working. Thanks for clarifying about how the shim works - that part makes sense. How come removing the router causes an error, but removing the appview doesn't?

Comment: That's because the router also references backbone. When you remove all the dependencies that require backbone, it won't be loaded anymore.

Comment: So to answer your question, it's because you removed the view first and then the router. Try the other way around, and you will see it will do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChristiMihai mentioned, Backbone created a global Backbone object, correct. Let me give you an example of what I do in my Require.js / Backbone / Handlebars app:

First, I include Require config in `<head>`:

```
var require_config = {
  baseUrl: "/javascripts",
  waitSeconds: 5,
  paths: {
    'cdnjs': 'http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs',
    'aspnetcdn': 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax',
    'cloudflare': 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs',
    'local': '/javascripts'
  }
}

if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.config(require_config);
} else {
  var require = require_config;
}
```

After that I bootstrap a require module, e.g:

```
define([
  'app'
],
function() {
  console.log('Homepage module');
  /*

  ... this is the meat of your app...
  you can add other dependencies beside `app` too

  */
});
```

Now `app` is the main dependency which resolves via baseUrl to `/javascripts/app.js` and includes all necessary deps in order, and looks like this:

```
define([
  'order!cdnjs/json2/20110223/json2',
  'order!cloudflare/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min',
  'order!cloudflare/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min',
  'order!handlebars/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.min',
  'order!lib/ns',
  'bootstrap'
], function(){});
```